# in C# can we do something like this List<? of CustomType>

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a custom type, which is abstract.
and will have some class to extend the abstract class.

somewhere i need to deal with a list of object which are  the children my custom abstract type.

i am wonder in C#, can i do somthing like this:

```
void Method(List<? is CustomType> objs)
{
}
```

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think what you are looking for is a generic method. Those are definitely supported:

```
void Method<T>(List<T> objs) where T: CustomType
{
}
```

MSDN on generics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 6):

```
void Method<T>(List<T> objs)
    where T : CustomType
{
}
```